# Angularjs ngTable doesn´t shows row just added

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have ngTable with some rows. 
My ngTable is showing into view:'configClinicasClinicas.html' without problem.

I have created a new view to add a row into "addClinica.html".
My data rows is coming from my local node server.

To test, I  initially loaded the ui-route state('configuracoes.clinicas.clinicas') to show the table.

After that, I click a button to load a new state('configuracoes.clinicas.addclinica') to add a new row. Next, I post the new data to server. So far so good, no problem until here.

The problem is that after I post the new data row to server,I use $state.go to load my table again but my new row just posted doesn´t appears in the table. I can see  the new row is coming from server, but  it is not showing in the table.

My new added row appears on the table as a blank row without data.

If I click again to add a new row I get the error of "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed".

I am a newbie with ngTable.

What  am I missiing here?

//Error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: row in $data track by row.id, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: {"clinica":{"id":6,"nome":"sadf","endereco":"sadf","bairro":"sadf","cidade":"sdfsaass","uf":"sdafasd","telefone":"sadfasd","isAtivo":true,"coord":{"id":2,"latitude":-49.4,"longitude":23.2}}}
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=row%20in%20%24data%20tr…%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22latitude%22%3A-49.4%2C%22longitude%22%3A23.2%7D%7D%7D
    at angular.js:68
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:30804)
    at $watchCollectionAction (angular.js:17677)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17814)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18080)
    at done (angular.js:12210)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12436)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12364)
```

//configClinicasClinicas.html'

```
     <p>
      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ui-sref="configuracoes.clinicas.addclinica">Add Clinic 
    </a>
   </p>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                <tr ng-repeat="row in $data track by row.id">
                  <td data-title="'Nome'" filter="{name: 'text'}" sortable="'nome'">{{row.nome}}</td>
                  <td align="center" valign="center" data-title="'Endereço'"> {{row.endereco}}</td>
                  <td align="center" valign="center" data-title="'Bairro'" > {{row.bairro}}</td>
                  <td align="center" valign="center" data-title="'Cidade'" > {{row.cidade}}</td>
                  <td align="center" valign="center" data-title="'Estado'" > {{row.uf}}</td>
                  <td align="center" valign="center" data-title="'Telefone'" > {{row.telefone}}</td>
                  <td align="center" valign="center" data-title="'Ativo'"> <span ng-class="row.isAtivo ? 'label label-info' : 'label label-danger' "> {{row.isAtivo ? "Ativo":"Inativo"}} </span></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
    </table>
```

//addClinica.html

```
<div class="col-md-9">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
         <legend>
            Dados da clínica
         </legend>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="registro">
            ID
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-4">
               <input id="registro" name="clinica.id"  ng-model="clinica.id" type="number" class="form-control inline">
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="nome" title="Nome">
            Nome&nbsp;*
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-4">
               <input name="clinica.nome" id="nome" ng-model="clinica.nome" class="form-control " type="text" required="required" maxlength="60">
            </div>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
      ...
      ....
      <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding pull-right">
         <div class="clearfix form-actions">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
               <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveClinica(clinica)">
               <i class="fa fa-check bigger-110"></i>
               Save
               </a>
               <a class="btn btn-success" ui-sref="smenupacientes.clinicas.clinicas()">
               <i class="fa fa-close bigger-110"></i>
               Cancel
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

//JS

```
angular.module("clinang", ["ngTable",  "ui.router","ui.bootstrap"]);

angular.module("clinang").config(function($stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
   //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);

   // the known route, with missing '/' - let's create alias
   $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/pacientes');

   // the unknown
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

   $stateProvider
 .... other states
 .state('configuracoes.clinicas.addclinica', {
      url: '/addclicnica',
      views:{
          'configclinicasaddclicnica@configuracoes.clinicas':{
            templateUrl: '/views/addClinica.html',
            controller: 'configClinicaClinicaAddClinicaCtrl'
          }
        }
    })

     .state('configuracoes.clinicas.clinicas', {
      url: '/configclinicasclinicas',
      views:{
          'configclinicasclinicas@configuracoes.clinicas':{
            templateUrl: '/views/configClinicasClinicas.html',
            controller: 'configClinicaClinicaCtrl'
          }
        }
    })
 });    


 //Controllers
 ngular.module("clinang").controller('configClinicaClinicaAddClinicaCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$state','NgTableParams', function($scope,$http, $state,NgTableParams) {
      $scope.clinica={};
      $scope.saveClinica=function(clinica){
        var coord={id:2, latitude:-49.4, longitude:23.2};
        clinica.coord=coord;
        $http.post('/clinicas',{clinica}).then(function(response){
            delete $scope.clinica;
            $state.go('configuracoes.clinicas.clinicas');
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
}]);

angular.module("clinang").controller('configClinicaClinicaCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$state','NgTableParams', function($scope,$http, $state,NgTableParams) {
      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        getData: function(params) {
        return $http.get('/clinicas',{params:{where:params}}).then(function(response){
            params.total(response.data.length); // recal. page nav controls
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            return response.data;
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
        })
      }})
}]);
```

Comment: tried using track by $index?

Comment: @Cameron Rodriguez  Hi, thank for your tip. But, I am using track by row.id because it´s unique. If I replace with track by $index the duplicate error dispappears, but the main problem continues: the new rows just added is no showing in the table.

Comment: This means you have duplicates in your `row.id` parameter

Comment: No, I haven´t. Here is my node.js server script with my data:var clinicas=[
{id:1,nome:'Clinica Santa Rosa',endereco:'Rua da alfandega,132', bairro:'Croatá',cidade:'Rio de Janeiro', uf:'RJ', telefone:'2412-2828', isAtivo:true,coord:coordenadas[0]},
{id:2,nome:'Clinica Santa Cecilica',endereco:'Rua da aurora,131', bairro:'Ilha de guraratiba',cidade:'Rio de Janeiro', uf:'RJ', telefone:'2412-2829', isAtivo:true,coord:coordenadas[1]}
];

Comment: What happens if you remove this line: `delete $scope.clinica;`?

Comment: @Alex there is no difference. After I add the new row and load the state to show the table again, I can see my ajax call results with all rows and  with the new row included. But, the table, instead of show the new row added, it shows only a blank row added on the bottom of the table  without the data just added.

Comment: Sorry Lex,, I typed Alex instead of Lex